# Unity3d camera rotation cut off after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make unity 3d multiplayer 1st shooter game and I am working on the player movement. Everything is fine when I run on unity editor, but when I build the game and play, the camera(1st person) rotation by it's mouse, cut off very often and it is different from when I run on unity editor. I guess it's problem of frame per second or something about that things, but I can't fix it. I tried lateupdate(), fixedupdate() and they didn't work either. Anyone who had meet this problem?

My code:

(This one is Update() function for my playerController)

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            float moveSpeed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed;
            float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            Vector3 moveDirection = (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * vertical) + (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * horizontal);
            moveDirection.y = 0;
            moveDirection.Normalize();
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y, moveDirection.z * moveSpeed);

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.01f)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed, rb.velocity.z);
            }
            rotationX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed * 300 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
```

(And this one is FixedUpdate() function for my cameraController)

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(playerTransform != null)
        {
            transform.position = playerTransform.TransformPoint(offset);
            transform.rotation = playerTransform.rotation;
        }
    }
```

I am really forward to show you video on unity editor and build, but unfortunately there is no way to upload videos. Or maybe there could be and I just don't know how.

Do you guys have any ideas? I am tried of doing this....

I tried Update(), FixedUpdate(), LateUpdate() and asked ChatGPT, Googled...

Comment: what do you mean by "cut off"? like the mouse will stop moving the view of the player randomly? make sure the unity editor has the same settings for FOV and resolution as your screen too

Comment: @DylanRobertson What i mean by "cut off" is that camera movement is not smooth. Camera should rotation smoothly but I move like running high quality of fps multiplayer game on very old laptop. But it is never problem of optimization or anything about profiling. I guess it's because of frame per second, but I don't know how to fix it. By the way, isn't there any way to upload videos on stackoverflow? I am new to this.

Comment: it might be because of fixed update? maybe try putting that code in update() instead of fixedUpdate()

Comment: It got worse.  Hmm. I tried FixedUpdate, LateUpdate, Update, used Time.deltaTime, and everything that I can do with my freakin head.

Comment: it might be worth pasting this code in a brand new blank project to see if the same thing happens, that way you can know if it's an issue with the camera code or if it's something else in the project.

Comment: I guess there's problem with my code. I did what you said, open new project and run the code at the project, and everything else is almost same. But what could be the problem in my code? Because everything works fine on the editor. But why that only happen after the build? I cannot understand the part. I never touched project setting or such a thing.

Comment: Hmmm i'm not too sure why, you could try checking out this code here https://www.sharpcoderblog.com/blog/unity-3d-fps-controller to see if it works. if this works you can replace your this code with your code line by line to see if where exactly the issue is maybe.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! @DylanRobertson You are my god!!! You saved me thank you so much!!!! I won't forget this!! THANK YOU MAN I LOVE YOU BUDDY!!!

Comment: :-) good luck with your project